# How to have outer class wait for inner AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, signals

I have an outer class method that executes an inner class extending AsyncTask, and I want that outer method to then sleep till the AsycnTask tells it to continue. Basically, I am pulling something from a DB in the inner class, and calling it from the outer class, however I need the outer class to wait till it has actually been retrieved before it tires to access it.

```
public class A{
    String response;
    public String returnResponse{
           new B().execute();

           // wait for signal from B

           return response;
    }

    private class B extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
          response = string pulled from online db;
          //once response has been set, signal A.returnResponce to stop waiting
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 new B().execute().get();
```

instead of your code

```
 new B().execute();
```

this will wait for signal from B.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
new B().execute().get();
```

instead of

```
new B().execute();
```

for make waiting until `AsyncTask` execution complete